# how to get real row indices R arrow package

Tags: r, dplyr, apache-arrow

let's imagine that I have a huge file divided into many pieces that I can read with an arrow

```
X <- iris
library(arrow)
# bigX a large file that is stored in chunks on disk out of memory
bigX <- arrow_table(X)
```

after filtering by some value `Sepal.Width == 3.8`, I get some of the data I need

```
library(dplyr)
 bigX %>% 
  filter(Sepal.Width == 3.8) %>% 
  collect()
```

..

```
 Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
1          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3    setosa
2          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3    setosa
3          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4    setosa
4          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2    setosa
5          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
6          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
```

My problem is that I also want to get real row indices from a whole huge selection.
like in this example.

```
X[X$Sepal.Width==3.8,]
```

..

```
    Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species
19           5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3    setosa
20           5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3    setosa
45           5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4    setosa
47           5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2    setosa
118          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica
132          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica
```

Comment: That is on your data model -- you need to add a column with the index. That way when later subset or filter you get the original position ("row index") as part of your selection.  There isn't really another way to do this.

Comment: @Dirk Eddelbuettel Yes, thanks, I suspected that I need to create a new column with real indices. But I also understand that the arrow itself remembers the real indices and I was hoping that maybe there is a way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to use `row_number()` directly ...

```r
library(dplyr)
arrow::arrow_table(iris) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  filter(Sepal.Width == 3.8) %>%
  collect()
# Warning: Expression row_number() not supported in Arrow; pulling data into R
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width   Species  rn
# 1          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3    setosa  19
# 2          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3    setosa  20
# 3          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4    setosa  45
# 4          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2    setosa  47
# 5          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica 118
# 6          7.9         3.8          6.4         2.0 virginica 132
```

but adding `duckdb` to the lazy pipeline, we can do some simple window functions (such as `row_number()`), as described [here](https://arrow-user2022.netlify.app/data-wrangling.html#example-7-window-functions):

```r
arrow::arrow_table(iris) %>%
  arrow::to_duckdb() %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  filter(Sepal.Width == 3.8) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 6 × 6
#   Sepal.Length Sepal.Width Petal.Length Petal.Width Species      rn
#          <dbl>       <dbl>        <dbl>       <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
# 1          5.7         3.8          1.7         0.3 setosa       19
# 2          5.1         3.8          1.5         0.3 setosa       20
# 3          5.1         3.8          1.9         0.4 setosa       45
# 4          5.1         3.8          1.6         0.2 setosa       47
# 5          7.7         3.8          6.7         2.2 virginica   118
# 6          7.9         3.8          6.4         2   virginica   132
```

This also works on multi-file datasets such as a directory (nested or not) of parquet files:

```r
arrow::write_dataset(mtcars, "~/Downloads/tempmt", partitioning = "cyl")
arrow::open_dataset("~/Downloads/tempmt/") %>%
  arrow::to_duckdb() %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  filter(disp > 300) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 11 × 12
#      mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb   cyl    rn
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#  1  18.7   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2     8    19
#  2  14.3   360   245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4     8    20
#  3  10.4   472   205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4     8    24
#  4  10.4   460   215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4     8    25
#  5  14.7   440   230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4     8    26
#  6  15.5   318   150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     3     2     8    27
#  7  15.2   304   150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2     8    28
#  8  13.3   350   245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4     8    29
#  9  19.2   400   175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     3     2     8    30
# 10  15.8   351   264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4     8    31
# 11  15     301   335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8     8    32
```

Though it's very important to do that step early in the pipeline ... if you do it after filtering, you won't get the real row numbers, since they are relative to the data that the point row numbers are added:

```r
arrow::open_dataset("~/Downloads/tempmt/") %>%
  arrow::to_duckdb() %>%
  filter(disp > 300) %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  collect()
# # A tibble: 11 × 12
#      mpg  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb   cyl    rn
#    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int> <dbl>
#  1  18.7   360   175  3.15  3.44  17.0     0     0     3     2     8     1
#  2  14.3   360   245  3.21  3.57  15.8     0     0     3     4     8     2
#  3  10.4   472   205  2.93  5.25  18.0     0     0     3     4     8     3
#  4  10.4   460   215  3     5.42  17.8     0     0     3     4     8     4
#  5  14.7   440   230  3.23  5.34  17.4     0     0     3     4     8     5
#  6  15.5   318   150  2.76  3.52  16.9     0     0     3     2     8     6
#  7  15.2   304   150  3.15  3.44  17.3     0     0     3     2     8     7
#  8  13.3   350   245  3.73  3.84  15.4     0     0     3     4     8     8
#  9  19.2   400   175  3.08  3.84  17.0     0     0     3     2     8     9
# 10  15.8   351   264  4.22  3.17  14.5     0     1     5     4     8    10
# 11  15     301   335  3.54  3.57  14.6     0     1     5     8     8    11
```

---

N.B., I'd really like to be able to combine this with the `add_filename()` faux-function,

```r
arrow::open_dataset("~/Downloads/tempmt/") %>%
  mutate(fn = add_filename()) %>%
  slice_head(n=3) %>%
  collect()
#    mpg disp  hp drat   wt qsec vs am gear carb cyl                                             fn
# 1 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.62 16.5  0  1    4    4   6 /home/r2/Downloads/tempmt/cyl=6/part-0.parquet
# 2 21.0  160 110 3.90 2.88 17.0  0  1    4    4   6 /home/r2/Downloads/tempmt/cyl=6/part-0.parquet
# 3 21.4  258 110 3.08 3.21 19.4  1  0    3    1   6 /home/r2/Downloads/tempmt/cyl=6/part-0.parquet
```

but alas it's not supported by duckdb,

```r
arrow::open_dataset("~/Downloads/tempmt/") %>%
  arrow::to_duckdb() %>%
  mutate(fn = add_filename(), rn = row_number()) %>%
  filter(disp > 400) %>%
  collect()
# Error in `collect()`:
# ! Failed to collect lazy table.
# Caused by error:
# ! rapi_prepare: Failed to prepare query SELECT *
# FROM (
#   SELECT *, add_filename() AS fn, ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS rn
#   FROM arrow_044
# ) q01
# WHERE (disp > 400.0)
# Error: Catalog Error: Scalar Function with name add_filename does not exist!
# Did you mean "add"?
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```

and `to_duckdb()` does not work on an object of class `"arrow_dplyr_query"`:

```r
arrow::open_dataset("~/Downloads/tempmt/") %>%
  mutate(fn = add_filename()) %>%
  arrow::to_duckdb() %>%
  mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
  filter(disp > 400) %>%
  collect()
# Error in `collect()`:
# ! Failed to collect lazy table.
# Caused by error:
# ! Invalid Input Error: Attempting to execute an unsuccessful or closed pending query result
# Error: Invalid Error: std::exception
# Run `rlang::last_trace()` to see where the error occurred.
```